# Pass parent attribute in metaclass

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass

The metaclass is defined as below:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        # uses attribute a,b,c,d
        a = namespace["a"]
        b = namespace["b"]
        c = namespace["c"]
        d = namespace["d"]
        ...
        return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
```

This metaclass uses attributes `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.
Now classes can be created with this `metaclass` as:

```
class A(metaclass=MyMeta):
    a = "etc/dev"
    b = 2
    c = "c"
    d = "d"

class B(metaclass=MyMeta):
    a = "etc/dev/null"
    b = 2
    c = "c"
    d = "d"
```

The attribute `a` is variable for each class.
I want to extract the constant attributes in a base class to avoid duplication:

```
class BaseClass:
    b = 2
    c = "c"
    d = "d"
```

and create classes using the metaclass as:

```
class A(BaseClass, metaclass=MyMeta):
    a = "/etc/dev"

class B(BaseClass, metaclass=MyMeta):
    a = "/etc/dev/null"
```

The metaclass complains that it can not find attribute `b` from parent class.

```
test_mode = namespace["b"]
KeyError: 'b'
```

Is there a way to pass attributes from parent to a child metaclass ?

***Constraint:*** Can not update the `MyMeta` metaclass as it's been borrowed/imported it from an existing library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by making the metaclass `__new__()` method *also* check the namespaces of all the base classes of the class being defined. Here's one way of doing it. Note that it filters out attributes in the namespaces that have dunder identifiers.

Since you can't change the meta class you "borrowed" a custom one is derived from it. This revised version of my earlier answer also uses the [`collection.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) class to make all the namespaces be considered without actually combining them all.

```
from collections import ChainMap
import re

class BorrowedMeta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        # uses attribute a,b,c,d
        a = namespace["a"]
        b = namespace["b"]
        c = namespace["c"]
        d = namespace["d"]
        ...
        return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)


def is_dunder(name):
    """Determine if name is a Python dunder identifier."""
    return re.match(r'^__[^\d\W]\w*\Z__$', name, re.UNICODE)


class MyMeta(BorrowedMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        chainmap = ChainMap(*[namespace] +
                             [{k: v for (k, v) in vars(base).items() if not(is_dunder(k))}
                                                    for base in bases])

        return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, {**chainmap}, **kwargs)


class BaseClass:
    b = 2
    c = "c"
    d = "d"

class A(BaseClass, metaclass=MyMeta):
    a = "/etc/dev"

class B(BaseClass, metaclass=MyMeta):
    a = "/etc/dev/null"


from pprint import pprint
pprint(vars(A))
print()
pprint(vars(B))
```

Output:

```
mappingproxy({'__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              'a': '/etc/dev',
              'b': 2,
              'c': 'c',
              'd': 'd'})

mappingproxy({'__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              'a': '/etc/dev/null',
              'b': 2,
              'c': 'c',
              'd': 'd'})
```

Comment: One constraint is I can not update the `MyMeta` metaclass as I have borrowed/imported it from an existing library. One way i tried is ```class CustomMeta(type, metaclass=MyMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs):
        # grab last base class, which in this case is Klass
        attrs["b"] = bases[-1].b
        attrs["c"] = bases[-1].c
        return super(CustomMeta, metacls).__new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs)
``` but metaclass does not work with parents.

Comment: That constraint  is a fairly significant omission to say the least.

Comment: Apologies for the omission, updated the description.

Comment: Turns out I was able to get my approach to work without too much trouble after all — i.e. by merely deriving a new metaclass from the unchangeable one you "borrowed".

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do what you want without changing the metaclass's behavior.

The problem is that the `namespace` argument that `MyMeta.__new__` is looking in contains *only* the values defined in the `class` statement for the new class. It doesn't contain anything inherited, since the class and it's bases haven't been combined yet (that's what `MyMeta.__new__` does when it calls `super().__new__` at the bottom of its implementation, *after* it has done its thing with the `a`/`b`/`c` variables).